# Kubernetes ingress rule

Tags: docker, websocket, kubernetes, kubectl, docker-ingress

I have a k8s `1.9.0` cluster and following is my ingress rule.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: my-ingress
 labels:
  app: report
annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
 rules:
  - host: "gayan.test.com"
    http:
     paths:
      - path: /report
        backend:
         serviceName: qc-report-svc
         servicePort: 80
     - path: /report/*
        backend:
         serviceName: qc-report-svc
         servicePort: 80
```

So I have two requests.

*Request one* - `https://gayan.test.com/report/ping` This request hit the pod and return the response.
(`GET /ping 200 302.079 ms - 63`)

*Request two* - `wss://gayan.test.com/report/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket`.
This request doesn't even hit the server. I think this is related to ingress rule.

My question is how can I send all the `/report` traffic to `qc-report-svc` service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Nginx Ingress Controller you need to add the `nginx.org/websocket-services` annotation to enable WebSocket support.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: my-ingress
 labels:
   app: report
annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  nginx.org/websocket-services: "qc-report-svc"
spec:
 rules:
  - host: "gayan.test.com"
    http:
     paths:
      - path: /report
        backend:
         serviceName: qc-report-svc
         servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Hi @Sebastian. Thanks for the answer. Yes. Im using Nginx ingress controller (gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.15)
.
But I don't think all the `/report` traffic route to `/report` path. Because I'm still seeing `400 error` on ingress controller.

Comment: The google variant uses different annotations and might not support your use case. In general I would advise to switch to the official Kubernetes Nginx ingress controller.